ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH
при установке python-libp2p возникает следующая ошибка.
ввожу в cmd:
pip install libp2p<br>

что-то идёт, и потом:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 410, in build_wheel
          return self._build_with_temp_dir(
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 395, in _build_with_temp_dir
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 487, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 208, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 103, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 184, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 200, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 969, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 968, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 368, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 968, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\command\build.py", line 132, in run
          self.run_command(cmd_name)
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 968, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "C:\Users\afsvu\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-iuijgclp\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 988, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "<string>", line 159, in run
      Exception: ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pynacl
Failed to build fastecdsa-any pynacl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fastecdsa-any, pynacl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

что делать?

Попробуйте сначала обновить pip, пишут это может помочь: python -m pip install -U pip А вообще зря вы весь вывод не привели. Возможно, там есть советы типа поставить дистрибутив C++ или что-то вроде того.

да, там написано про c++

building 'fastecdsa.curvemath' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for fastecdsa-any
Building wheel for pynacl (pyproject.toml) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

я скачал то что там было по ссылке но проблема осталась

Мало скачать, нужно ещё установить )  Но pip всё же обновите.
